# How can I dynamic get combination/permutation of groups in python?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have 3 groups

```
[1,2] [4,5] [a,b]
```

I want the permutations/combinations of these like this

```
1  4  a
1  5  a
1  4  b
1  5  b
2  4  a    
2  5  a
2  4  b
2  5  b
12 4  a
12 5  a
12 4  b
12 5  b
12 4  ab
12 5  ab
1  45 a
2  45 a
1  45 b
2  45 b
1  45 ab
2  45 ab
1  4  ab
2  5  ab
12 45 ab
```

This arrays can grow and won't alway be the same size, so the permutation will increase.

I got this so far.

```
from itertools import *

bag1 = [1, 2]
bag2 = [4, 5]
bag3  = ['a', 'b']

bags = []

bags.append(bag1)
bags.append(bag2)
bags.append(bag3)

comb = list(product(*bags))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your piece of code, you need to use the cartesian product (product), on all the possible combinations of your starting 'bags':

```
from itertools import product, combinations

def comb_bag(bag):
    new_bag = []
    for n in range(1, 1+len(bag)):
        new_bag += list(combinations(bag, n))

    return new_bag

bag1 = [1, 2]
bag2 = [4, 5]
bag3 = ['a', 'b']

comb = list(product(comb_bag(bag1), comb_bag(bag2), comb_bag(bag3)))

for e in comb:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it looks like you are trying to take a product of non-empty subsets of each group. We can do this almost verbatim using itertools: first, define a function giving non-empty subsets and then apply product.

```
from itertools import *


def subsets(xs):
    for k in range(1, len(xs) + 1):
        yield from combinations(xs, k)


lst = [[1, 2], [4, 5], ["a", "b"]]

result = list(product(*map(subsets, lst)))

# first few values
# [((1,), (4,), ('a',)),
# ((1,), (4,), ('b',)),
# ((1,), (4,), ('a', 'b')),
# ((1,), (5,), ('a',)),
# ((1,), (5,), ('b',)),

# pretty print
for line in result[:5]:
    line = " ".join("".join(map(str, tok)) for tok in line)
    print(line)


# 1 4 a
# 1 4 b
# 1 4 ab
# 1 5 a
# 1 5 b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is get the combinations of each group individually and then get the product of the groups. From there, you can do some processing if you want strings or whatever.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

groups = [[1, 2], [3, 4], ['a', 'b']]

# Note you want groups of all sizes:
sub_combs = []
for g in groups:
    group_combs = []
    for r in range(len(g)):
        combs = combinations(g, r+1) #Combinations of all (nonempty) sizes
        group_combs += list(combs)
    sub_combs.append(group_combs)
final_combs = list(product(*sub_combs))

final_combs

[((1,), (3,), ('a',)),
 ((1,), (3,), ('b',)),
 ((1,), (3,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((1,), (4,), ('a',)),
 ((1,), (4,), ('b',)),
 ((1,), (4,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((1,), (3, 4), ('a',)),
 ((1,), (3, 4), ('b',)),
 ((1,), (3, 4), ('a', 'b')),
 ((2,), (3,), ('a',)),
 ((2,), (3,), ('b',)),
 ((2,), (3,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((2,), (4,), ('a',)),
 ((2,), (4,), ('b',)),
 ((2,), (4,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((2,), (3, 4), ('a',)),
 ((2,), (3, 4), ('b',)),
 ((2,), (3, 4), ('a', 'b')),
 ((1, 2), (3,), ('a',)),
 ((1, 2), (3,), ('b',)),
 ((1, 2), (3,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((1, 2), (4,), ('a',)),
 ((1, 2), (4,), ('b',)),
 ((1, 2), (4,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((1, 2), (3, 4), ('a',)),
 ((1, 2), (3, 4), ('b',)),
 ((1, 2), (3, 4), ('a', 'b'))]
```